# Specify Required Props for a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I would like to specify the props that are required for a component so that when that particular component is used, I know what data needs to be supplied to it, how do i do that?

e.g.
// basic gist of my requirement

```
class ABC extends React.Component{

  render(){
   return (<View>this.props.reqProp</View>)
  }
}


class ABC_Caller extends React.Component{

  render(){
   return ( <ABC reqProp={'testData'} /> )
  }
}
```

In the above example when using the component ABC I would like to somehow know that `reqProp` is a required prop which I must supply to `ABC` without which it will crash.

I would prefer this check to be compile time and not run time.

Comment: `PropTypes` is perfectly to that! See the docs and example here  https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**PropTypes**](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html):

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ABC extends React.Component{
  render(){
   return (<View>this.props.reqProp</View>)
  }
}
ABC.propTypes = {
  reqProp: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Notice you are both specifying the `string` type and that it is required (`isRequired`).

If you want compile-time errors, you can use an IDE that supports [**Flow**](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) (or run the cli).

[Using **Flow**, you can declare the Props](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/), and mark those not required with a `?`:

```js
type Props = {
  reqProp: string,
  notRequiredProp?: string
};
class ABC extends React.Component<Props> {  // notice <Props>
  render(){
    return (<View>this.props.reqProp</View>)
  }
}
```